# how to change laravel db query builder bracket

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, post, query-builder

need to ask,
currently i'm using laravel and db query builder to create the function below.
Requirement is to get the query result without the bracket / object but with { }

Function is below :

```html
       $score = DB::table('m_player_scorecard')
            ->where('session_id', '=', $sessionID)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();

        $scoreArr = json_decode(json_encode($score), true);

        return response()
            ->json($scoreArr);
```

when i try to hit from postman :

```html
[
    {
        "id": 153,
        "session_id": "9e3bb8296fd195c66ced470ec50301385f6cd31a17012e26fd0099bdf821338c",
        "round_order": 2,
        "player_one_id": 1,
        "score_one": 10,
        "player_two_id": 2,
        "score_two": 10,
        "player_three_id": 3,
        "score_three": 30,
        "player_four_id": 4,
        "score_four": 40,
        "notes": null,
        "created_at": "2020-06-06 18:15:27",
        "updated_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 152,
        "session_id": "9e3bb8296fd195c66ced470ec50301385f6cd31a17012e26fd0099bdf821338c",
        "round_order": 1,
        "player_one_id": 1,
        "score_one": 10,
        "player_two_id": 2,
        "score_two": 20,
        "player_three_id": 3,
        "score_three": 30,
        "player_four_id": 4,
        "score_four": 40,
        "notes": null,
        "created_at": "2020-06-06 18:14:39",
        "updated_at": null
    }
]
```

I need to change the bracket [ ] to { }.
How to do that?

Thanks before

Comment: Query builder bracket? That's a JSON array, why would you want them gone?

Comment: [] = an array, and you response it's an array, and a valid json too. If you remove them, you lose it

Comment: Sry i mean to change from [ ] to { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have updated your question, so I updated my answer :

```
$remove = array("[", "]");
$replace   = array("{", "}");
$newJson = str_replace($remov, $replace, $oldJson);
```

Comment: Let me try to replace